# Mysql one Parent multiple Child result without repeating Parent rows

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am building a CMS with Codeigniter and MYSQL. and have a table like this.

```
CREATE TABLE parent
(`parentId` int, `parentName` varchar(50));

INSERT INTO parent
(`parentId`, `parentName`)
VALUES
(1, 'Movie'),
(2, 'Food'),
(3, 'Sports');

CREATE TABLE child
(`childId` int, `parentId` int,`childName` varchar(50));
INSERT INTO child
(`childId`, `parentId`, `childName`)
VALUES
(1, 1, 'Harry Potter'),
(2, 3, 'Foot Ball'),
(3, 2, 'Pizza'),
(4, 2, 'Burger'),
(5, 1, 'Avengers'),
(6, 1, 'Fury'),
(7, 3, 'Cycling');
```

And want output to be printed output like this

```
foreach($parent as $parentData):
echo"<h4>".$parentData->parentName."</h4>";
echo"<ul>";
 foreach($child as childData):
 echo"<li>".$childData->childName."</li>";
 endforeach;
echo"</ul>"
endforeach;
```

which produces this

```
<h4>Movie</h4>
<ul>
<li>Harry Potter</li>
<li>Avengers</li>
<li>Fury</li>
</ul>
<h4>Food</h4>
<ul>
<li>Pizza</li>
<li>Burger</li>
</ul>
<h4>Sports</h4>
<ul>
<li>Foot Ball</li>
<li>Cycling</li>
</ul>
```

Any tweaking of the code is welcomed.
As i have been trying this for the past few hours.
Thanks in advance.

Update:
I implemented the answer to my code as CodeGodie suggested and added a view like this.

```
foreach ($result as $arr) {
if (!isset($final[$arr["parentName"]])) {
    $final[$arr["parentName"]] = array();
}
array_push($final[$arr["parentName"]], $arr);
}
foreach ($final as $parent=> $childs) {
echo $parent."<br>";
foreach ($childs as $child) {
    print_r($child) ;
}
}
```

Now i got the result i was expecting

Comment: I don't get it, you want output but the queries you are providing are `INSERT` and `CREATE` queries, not `SELECT`, you want us to provide the `SELECT` queries?

Comment: I am searching for select query. I have tried left join of both tables but i am not able to use it in a foreach loop since parent table get repeated.

Comment: well, yes, that is how a join works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this. However I would use the following approach:

1. You need to create the following SQL query:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM parent p
   JOIN child c ON c.parentId = p.parentId
   ORDER BY parentName
   ```

   Or in Codeigniter:

   ```
   $this->db->select("*");
   $this->db->from("parent p");
   $this->db->join("child c", "c.parentId = p.parentId ");
   $this->db->order_by("parentName");
   $q = $this->db->get();
   return $q->result_array();
   ```

   which will give you a result of something like this:

   ```
   $result = array(
       array(
          "parentId" => 2,
          "parentName" => "Food",
          "childId" => 3,
          "childName" => "Pizza",
       ),
       array(
          "parentId" => 2,
          "parentName" => "Food",
          "childId" => 4,
          "childName" => "Burger",
       ),
       array(
          "parentId" => 1,
          "parentName" => "Movie",
          "childId" => 1,
          "childName" => "Harry Potter",
       ),
       array(
          "parentId" => 1,
          "parentName" => "Movie",
          "childId" => 5,
          "childName" => "Avengers",
       )
   );
   ```
2. Iterate through your results:

   ```
   foreach ($result as $arr) {
       if (!isset($final[$arr["parentName"]])) {
           $final[$arr["parentName"]] = array();
       }
       array_push($final[$arr["parentName"]], $arr);
   }

   var_dump($final);
   ```

   this will give you a result like this which you can then iterate to build your HTML:

   ```
   array (size=2)
     'Food' => 
       array (size=2)
         0 => 
           array (size=4)
             'parentId' => int 2
             'parentName' => string 'Food' (length=4)
             'childId' => int 3
             'childName' => string 'Pizza' (length=5)
         1 => 
           array (size=4)
             'parentId' => int 2
             'parentName' => string 'Food' (length=4)
             'childId' => int 4
             'childName' => string 'Burger' (length=6)
     'Movie' => 
       array (size=2)
         0 => 
           array (size=4)
             'parentId' => int 1
             'parentName' => string 'Movie' (length=5)
             'childId' => int 1
             'childName' => string 'Harry Potter' (length=12)
         1 => 
           array (size=4)
             'parentId' => int 1
             'parentName' => string 'Movie' (length=5)
             'childId' => int 5
             'childName' => string 'Avengers' (length=8)
   ```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for group concat

https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/

Using this, you can select a comma separated list of child values. Then in your PHP you would simply need to explode on the comma and then loop through that.

Bear in mind the default group_concat limit is often quite low so you will probably need to increase this - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len

Answer (score 0):

This query will get all the data:

```
SELECT parent.parentName, child.childName 
FROM parent 
INNER JOIN child on parent.parentId = child.parentId;
```

And return it as:

```
------------------------------
parentname    |    childName
------------------------------
Movie         |    Harry Potter
Movie         |    Avengers
Movie         |    Fury
et cetera...
```